# Mercurial: message "abort: index 00changelog.i is corrupted!" after running a sed command. How to deal with it?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, corrupt

I have a project versioned by Mercurial. Once, I ran a command such as...

```
$ find . -type f | xargs sed -i.bkp 's/my_func/another_func/'
```

...in this project. Then Mercurial just stopped to work on it:

```
$ hg status
abort: index 00changelog.i is corrupted!
```

The file `00changelog.i` did not contain the replaced string, and even if I move `00changelog.i.bkp` to `00changelog.i` the problem persisted. `hg verify` didn't help either:

```
$ hg verify
abort: index 00changelog.i is corrupted!
```

I solved this problem by cloning the project from my remote repository in another directory and then copying `.hg` from my cloned repository to the corrupted one. However, I wonder: is there another more practical way of solving it? BTW, why does this problem happens if the "corrupted" file is not even altered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that there are **two** 00changelog.i files:

- one in .hg/00changelog.i which is a small backwards-compatibility placeholder for ancient versions
- another (the one you damaged) in .hg/store/00changelog.i

Comment: You are right! I did not know it. However, it does not solve the question: I moved the `.hg/store/00changelog.i.bkp` to `.hg/store/00changelog.i` and the problem persists.

Comment: Did you restore the corresponding .d file too? If you did multiple seds and thereby overwrote your backups, you'll be out of luck. Otherwise, it's not magic: put the bits that were there before back and it will work again.

Comment: Well, I did not find any `.d` file, but then I ran `for f in $(find .hg -name '*.bkp') ; do mv $f ${f/.bkp/} ; done` and could make the repository work again.

Answer (score -2):

I'd use convert to re-generate the repo or transplant to move the patches to the new one. Good luck.

Comment: Interesting... Are you talking about the `convert` extension? How could I use it to regenerate the repository?